# Can not install conda package via subprocess library

Tags: python, bash, anaconda

How can I install conda package with help of python script?

I want to install anaconda package with help of python code.

My code

```
# src.py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(["conda"] + ["install", "python=3.8", "pyyaml", "-y"], shell=True)
```

How to reproduce

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.8
conda activate test_env
python src.py
```

I am running the script and i see no errors and anaconda help text

```
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...

conda is a tool for managing and deploying applications, environments and packages.
...
```

**Problem** - the pyyaml package is not installed in my anaconda env (was checking with help of `conda list`)

P.S

```
OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04
conda version 4.10.3
```